# How do you write a presto query to split a string into its own column

Tags: sql, presto, qubole

Trying to splint a string into multiple columns in qubole using presto query.

`{"field0":[{"startdate":"2022-07-13","lastnightdate":"2022-07-16","adultguests":5,"childguests":0,"pets":null}]}`

Would like startdate,lastnightdate,adultguests,childguests and pets into its own column.

I tried to unnest string but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data looks a lot like json, so you can process it using [json functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) first (parse, extract, cast to `array(map(varchar, json))` or `array(map(varchar, varcchar))`) and then flatten with `unnest`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(json_payload) AS (
    VALUES 
        ('{"field0":[{"startdate":"2022-07-13","lastnightdate":"2022-07-16","adultguests":5,"childguests":0,"pets":null}]}')
) 

-- query
select m['startdate'] startdate,
    m['lastnightdate'] lastnightdate,
    m['adultguests'] adultguests,
    m['childguests'] childguests,
    m['pets'] pets
from dataset,
unnest(cast(json_extract(json_parse(json_payload), '$.field0') as array(map(varchar, json)))) t(m)
```

Output:

| startdate | lastnightdate | adultguests | childguests | pets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-16 | 5 | 0 | null |